# Does the Ardiuno Nano have a Serial2 port?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

Does the Arduino Nano provide a [`Serial2` interface like the Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/serial)? If so what pins are the Rx/Tx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Arduino Nano uses either an ATmega168 or ATmega368 microcontroller, and these only have a single UART. Just like a regular Arduino (Uno or Duemilanove).

They do have both I2C and SPI, which you can use for communicating with another Arduino, and for some applications you can use [SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/hu/Reference/SoftwareSerial), which allows you to do async serial on any pins, but also uses up a lot of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Google says no, there is **one** serial port but it's connected to the USB chip, also see [link to Arduino Nano tech page](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano).

Comment: I cannot find a reference to a *second* `Serial` at the linked page.

Comment: Indeed, there is only **one**. Maybe you are meaning the RX / TX pins, these are the same pins that are used for the FTDI chip.

Comment: But the question is about a second port. So either we misunderstand each other or your answer is not appropriate for  the question.